# Strange behaviour of MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, first of all I want to excuse if my question will be stupid, I have very low experience in node.js/mongodb/etc.
I have next schema of my documents in mongoDB:

```
var schema = new mg.Schema({
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    lastLog: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
var User = mg.model('users', schema);
```

I'm trying to find all documents with token filed equals to tok and if can't find any documents - create it, or if there is document - update it field lastLog.

```
User.find({ token: tok }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) util.error('error: ', err);
    else {
        if (docs && docs.length == 0) {
            var u = new User({ token: tok });
            u.save();
        }
        else User.update({ token: tok }, { $set: { lastLog: Date.now() } });
    }
});
```

But, I got strange error(as for me) in line:

```
        u.save();
```

"Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters, at new ObjectID."

I can't understand why it is appears here, 'coz in all examples in Internet nobody has same error.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: That error message doesn't make any sense unless you have an ObjectID field in your user schema that you're not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below;

```
var u = new User();
u.token = tok;
u.save(function(err) {
   if (err) handleError(err);
}
```